# Blog posts with Tag Cloud filter does not work on the search results - Sitecore 9.2 and SXA 1.9

Tags: sxa, content-search, taxonomy

I have created the blog component based on the below link

https://alan-null.github.io/2017/12/sxa-blog

Somehow, the filter does not work using the SXA tags.

**What I have done:**

Created Blog Module

Created Blog home and Blog post templates

Created partial and page designs

Used Tag cloud rendering for the blog category based on tags for blog base 
partial design

Used search results rendering to display list of blog posts

The Load more is implemented to display 12 results on page load and 12 more every click.

**Issue:** 
The blog post search results are not getting filtered based on the tag filter selected.

The tag was appearing in URL with hash tag #SxaTags=home loans but the same url param is not hitting in ajax call that is hitting to render the search results.

Blog Landing page URL: https://domain/global/Blog-Root

Blog Filtered URL: https://domain/global/Blog-Root#SxaTags=financial%20planning

The below ajax URL doesn't change at all for the tag filter based search and returns the same results everytime.

**Ajax Request URL**: 
https://domain/global/sxa/search/results/?s={B862EBF3-0E31-4886-AAF4-DA1CCCBE525B}&itemid={DAC6B90F-DFFF-419F-A29F-18C09BC69ECF}&sig=article-search-results&p=12&o=Published%2CDescending&v=%7B2F0BD790-9E23-4DC2-9B6D-DBC64717A715%7D

[image]

Is there anything that is missing here?

Comment: Yes, hotfix is available for this issue

Comment: Hey Mark, Can you tell what is the hotfix for this issue.

Comment: You have to contact Sitecore Support.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I have got the support ticket raised for this.

Comment: Just Update, I have removed the signature and the filter does work for the single word tag fitler.                             
Working: https://domain/global/Blog-Root#SxaTags=insurance                       Not Working: https://domain/global/Blog-Root#SxaTags=credit%20cards

Comment: @RajuBalagam : I too had this issue that search filters are not working for filters that has space in it. I had filter named "Case studies" and its not working. But filter with "Press" and "News" is working. So i contacted Sitecore support and they registered this as a bug.

Comment: @Sreekrishnan Thank you for the update. I have got the patch from Sitecore support and that fixed the issue. Thank you all for the support.

Comment: @Raju Balagam I have the same issue, it also get fixed when I remove the search results signature. However, I need to keep the signature. So did you manage to find a solution for this issue without removing the signature? or is it a sitecore issue and i need to contact sitecore support for this?

Comment: @Raju Balagam also i'm not sure i understand the root cause of this issue! would you please help?

Comment: Hello All, Sorry it took a bit of time to respond. There is support hotfix 371494 provided by the Sitecore support team.