# SxaTags is not working with SearchResults signature

Tags: sxa, search-facet

I am using `Sitecore 9.3 and SXA`, when I used the tag cloud with a searchresults component without having signature it worked fine but when I added a searchresults signature it stopped filtering in the following scenario:

I have only one search result in my page with search signature "mysearchresults" and i am using the tag cloud in another page and when i click on the tag cloud it redirects me to : {Site URL}/Search#sxatags=tagtest instead of : {Site URL}/Search#mysearchresults_sxatags=tagtest

in which the first URL is not filtering as it doesn't include search signature.

I tried to rename the name of SxaTags facet to my signature "mysearchresults_sxatags" it worked fine and the URL is changed to "{Site URL}/Search#mysearchresults_sxatags=tagtest". But this made another problem that the name of the signature is viewed in the page.

So, is there a way to append "#mysearchresults_sxatags=tagtest" in the URL while redirecting to searchResults page? or any other solutions?

Comment: Looks like this is similar problem -> https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/22820/blog-posts-with-tag-cloud-filter-does-not-work-on-the-search-results-sitecore . You need to contact Sitecore Support